# Printing subset of ArcMap layers in black and white?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, symbology, printing, color

I am working in ArcMap

Is it possible to print a select few layers in black and white and have one or two layers print in color?

Comment: Can you just symbolize the layers differently.  The layers you want B&W just use greyscale symbols, and for the others use color ?

Comment: That is what i am trying to avoid.  I need two sets of plans one in full color and the other just to have certain layers in color.  I can elaborate further if you would like.

Comment: please do elaborate, i dont think i fully understand what you are trying to do.  without further (clarifying) information i would just create two mxds, one symbolized with all the layers in colors, and the other symbolized mainly in b&w with the chosen layers symbolized in color. why are you trying to avoid doing that?

Comment: These are vey large files and there are multiple mxd's i would have to change roughly 15 layers in each.

Comment: Maybe someone else knows another way, but as far as I know there is no way to do this on the fly for a couple of layers.

Comment: Most printers or plotters have a print 'black & white' option might be worth looking into.

Comment: @Mapperz How would that address "a select few layers in black and white and have **one or two layers print in color**"?  I think it would print all in black and white.

Answer (score 2):

The most practical route I've found to date is:

1. Turn off all *keep-my-colours* layers in table of contents
2. From Data View export the map to an tiff image, with `.tfw` world file
3. Edit export.tif in Photoshop, Gimp, ... and convert to Greyscale. You might want to change levels for light tones like yellow (*don't* resample, clip, or anything else that changes pixel dimensions)
4. Copy `export.tfw` to `greyscaled.tfw`
5. Bring greyscaled.tif back into ArcMap
6. Turn off *turn-grey-scale layers* and turn back on *keep-my-colours*

This approach has significant drawbacks as all the exported layers are flattened into one and you can't rearrange order without redoing the whole exercise. It also doesn't work for well for maps with multiple data frames.

On the other hand, it can be significantly faster than changing symbols for each of the layers one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest that you will get to doing this is to:

1. Have a black and white layer file that corresponds to any coloured layers that you want to greyshade
2. Use ArcPy to remove the coloured layer and replace it with the black and white layer

Answer (score 0):

I get this request a lot, to make a black and white copy.  And I usually go with the printer option to print black and white.  Also, after you export a pdf, you can convert it to black and white as another option.  Sometimes neither of these looks very good. So I just have to manually change the colors to something neutral in the mxd.

Comment: How would this do the bolded bit in "print a select few layers in black and white and **have one or two layers print in color**"?